# div width not updating on resize

Tags: html, css

I'm probably missing something basic here.

[Here's the code:](http://plnkr.co/edit/Rduh12z7RkG3aTuAKMjm?p=preview)

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" />
        </div>
        <div class="inner">
             <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.outer {
  height: 30%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.inner {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
img {
   position: relative;
   display: inline;
   height: 100%;
   width: auto;
}
```

[Here's the preview](http://embed.plnkr.co/Rduh12z7RkG3aTuAKMjm/preview)

**What I'm trying to achieve:**
I want both images to scale to 100% height of .outer div while maintaining aspect ratio *and* I want .inner div to have the width of the image it contains.

**Problem:**
When I grab the bottom of window and downsize:

In Chrome: the height of images and divs is changing properly, but width of .inner divs and images is not updated, which results in changing images' aspect ratios.

In Firefox: the images are scaled properly, but the width of .inner divs is not updated.

When I grab the bottom of window and upsize:

Both in Chrome and Firefox: the images are scaled properly, but the width of .inner divs is not updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the `height` of `.outer` div to `30%` of `body`. So, when you shrink the bowser window the and the `height` of body becomes shorter. Eventually the aspect ratio will not maintain.

You can set a minimum height to the `.outer` div. For example- **190px**

```
.outer {
    height: 30%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    min-height: 190px; /* Add this */
}
```

By doing this, the `height` of `.outer` div will remain `30%` of `body`s `height` but this will not becomes shorter than 190px.

Hope this idea will help you.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to maintain the aspect ratio of .outer div. I just care about images ratios, and these should be kept by using {height: 100%; width: auto;} but this stops working after I wrap them with .inner divs

Comment: @kihu Well, the image ratios are actually maintaining if you refresh the browser after shrinking the browser window. But it's updating live while resizing. I'll see if there's a way to make the changes live also.

Comment: Thanks! For what is worth, when I remove .inner divs, everything updates fine. But I need them, unfortunately.